# Strange query when execute SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

When I execute

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

By mysql admin user
I always see this line :

```
select * from user where email='' AND (SELECT * FROM (SELECT(SLEEP(5-(IF(ORD(MID((SELECT IFNULL(CAST(email AS CHAR),0x20) FROM admin_new.`user` ORDER BY email LIMIT 105,1),5,1))>102,0,5)))))ylrK) AND 'ncED'='ncED'
```

each time is different

```
select * from user where email='' AND (SELECT * FROM (SELECT(SLEEP(5-(IF(ORD(MID((SELECT IFNULL(CAST(email AS CHAR),0x20) FROM admin_new.`user` ORDER BY email LIMIT 106,1),4,1))>96,0,5)))))rePG) AND 'xuFI'='xuFI'
```

what is that?
is it normal?
how can i found it in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that your site is vulnerable to SQL injection and you are seeing an exploit in action.

Basically this query is investigating your database structure, to let the attacker the information about table and column names. After learning it they can try to extract the information they need.

Apparently the leak is where `select * from user where email=` is used.

In case you are using PHP, refer to this question to learn how to protect your code from SQL injection: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You are right , select * from user was only in one page , I forbid it , and it fixed ,

Comment: is there a way to see what attacker did? @Your Common Sense

Comment: As I said above, this is investigating query, that extracts the information about your database structure. So I would  tell that nothing harmful is done yet. But it could be not the first attack though.